# How to derive $\mathcal{L}\{ \log^2(1+t)\}(s) = \log(2/s^3 + 2/s^2 + 1/s)$?

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform, hypergeometric-function

I aim to determine the Laplace transform of
$\log^2(1+t)$.
Apparently, Mathematica gives me a closed formula
$\log(2/s^3 + 2/s^2 + 1/s)$. Any idea how to obtain this formula?

I though run into a hypergeometric function:
$ \begin{aligned}\mathcal{L} \left\{ \log^2(1+\cdot) \right\}(s)&=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}\log^2 (1+t) \, dt =e^s\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-st}\log^2 (t) \, dt \\
&= e^s \left( \mathcal{L} \left\{ \log^2 \right\}(s) - \int_{0}^{1} e^{-st}\log^2 (t) \, dt \right)\\
&= \frac{e^s}{s} \left( \frac{\pi^2}{6} + \gamma^2 - \log^2(s) e^{-s} - 2 \log(s) E_1(s) - \underbrace{ \int_0^s e^{-u} \log^2(u) du }_{F(1, 1, 1; 2, 2, 2; -s)}\right) \end{aligned} $

Comment: Well, that's clearly wrong. For starters, it would be negative if $s=3$.

Comment: ok thanks, I just typed: f[t] = Log(1+t)^2; LaplaceTransform[f[t],t,s]

Comment: _Wolfram Alpha_ can only get a result for a specific choice of $s$. It looks like the Laplace transform is expressible in terms of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function).

Comment: I did not used the Wolfram Alpha interface but a Mathematica language input

Comment: Mathematica **13.3.0** give me: $2 e^s G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(s\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,0 \\
 -1,-1,-1 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$ if I expand I get: $-2 e^s \, _3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-s)+\frac{\pi ^2 e^s}{6 s}+\frac{\gamma ^2 e^s}{s}+\frac{e^s \log ^2(s)}{s}+\frac{2 \gamma  e^s \log (s)}{s}$

Comment: I imagine @MariusIwaniuk's expression, which generalizes examples I tried in WA, will be equivalent to your result in terms of a hypergeometric function, as opposed to the elementary result my first comment addressed.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk do you see a error in the code I used?